# Complex factorization .

Tags: factoring

What would be the factorizarion of the following term ?

> $$15x^{2}-24y^{2}-6z^{2}+2xy+24yz-zx$$

I tried to convert it into perfect square like $$(a+b+c){2}$$ , but to no purpose. What should I do ?

Comment: I got $(5x-6y+3z)(3x+4y-2z)$, is that right?

Comment: Please show how you did it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  write it as a quadratic in $x$ (for example) and solve it for the roots which then allow factoring:

$$
15x^{2}+(2y-z)x-24y^{2}-6z^{2}+24yz
$$

Note that the constant (in $x$) term is:

$$
-24y^{2}-6z^{2}+24yz = -6 (2 y - z)^2
$$

Then the discriminant happens to conveniently end up being a square:

$$
\Delta_x = (2y-z)^2 + 4\cdot15\cdot 6 (2y-z)^2 = 361 (2 y - z)^2
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot ...

Answer (score 0):

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 15 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 30 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
30 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 722 }{ 15 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 15 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 30 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
30 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
2 &  - 48 & 24 \\ 
 - 1 & 24 &  - 12 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$  15 \left(x + \frac{y}{15} - \frac{z}{30} \right)^2 - \frac{361}{15} \left( y - \frac{z}{2} \right)^2 = 15 x^2 - 24 y^2 - 6 z^2 + 24 yz -zx + 2xy \; \; , $$
$$ 15^2 \left(x + \frac{y}{15} - \frac{z}{30} \right)^2 - 19^2 \left( y - \frac{z}{2} \right)^2 = 15 \left(  15 x^2 - 24 y^2 - 6 z^2 + 24 yz -zx + 2xy \right) \; \; , $$
$$ \left(15x + y - \frac{z}{2} \right)^2 -  \left(19 y - \frac{19z}{2} \right)^2 = 15 \left(  15 x^2 - 24 y^2 - 6 z^2 + 24 yz -zx + 2xy \right) \; \; , $$
$$ \left( 15x + 20 y - 10 z  \right)  \left( 15x -18 y +9 z  \right)  = 15 \left(  15 x^2 - 24 y^2 - 6 z^2 + 24 yz -zx + 2xy \right) \; \; ,  $$
$$ \left( 3x + 4 y - 2 z  \right)  \left( 5x -6 y +3 z  \right)  =    15 x^2 - 24 y^2 - 6 z^2 + 24 yz -zx + 2xy  \; \; .  $$

I like it. If we get diagonal matrix $D$ with diagonal entries $A,-B,0,$ but $AB$ is not a rational square, then we get a factorization where some coefficients involve square roots.

$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
30 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
2 &  - 48 & 24 \\ 
 - 1 & 24 &  - 12 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 15 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 15 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 15 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
30 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 722 }{ 15 }  &  \frac{ 361 }{ 15 }  \\ 
 - 1 &  \frac{ 361 }{ 15 }  &  - 12 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 30 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 15 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 30 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 15 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 30 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
30 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 722 }{ 15 }  &  \frac{ 361 }{ 15 }  \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 361 }{ 15 }  &  -  \frac{ 361 }{ 30 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 15 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 15 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 30 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
30 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 722 }{ 15 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 15 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
30 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
2 &  - 48 & 24 \\ 
 - 1 & 24 &  - 12 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 15 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
30 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 722 }{ 15 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 15 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 30 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
30 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 722 }{ 15 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 15 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 30 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
30 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
2 &  - 48 & 24 \\ 
 - 1 & 24 &  - 12 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Answer (score 0):

I made one up. It does factor, just needs a $\sqrt {13}$
$$  x^2 + 12 y^2 + 29 z^2 + 38 yz + 18 zx + 10 xy  $$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
5 & 1 & 0 \\ 
9 & 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 13 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 5 & 9 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 5 & 9 \\ 
5 & 12 & 19 \\ 
9 & 19 & 29 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$  x^2 + 12 y^2 + 29 z^2 + 38 yz + 18 zx + 10 xy = (x+5y+9z)^2 - 13(y+2z)^2 $$
$$  x^2 + 12 y^2 + 29 z^2 + 38 yz + 18 zx + 10 xy \; \; = \; \;  \left(x + \left(5 + \sqrt{13}\right) y + \left(9 + 2 \sqrt {13}\right) z \right) \; \; \cdot \; \; \left(x + \left(5 - \sqrt{13}\right) y + \left(9 - 2 \sqrt {13}\right) z \right)  $$

===========================================================

$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 5 & 9 \\ 
5 & 12 & 19 \\ 
9 & 19 & 29 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 5 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 5 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 5 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 9 \\ 
0 &  - 13 &  - 26 \\ 
9 &  - 26 & 29 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 &  - 9 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 5 &  - 9 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 5 & 9 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 13 &  - 26 \\ 
0 &  - 26 &  - 52 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 5 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 5 & 9 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 13 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 5 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 &  - 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 5 & 9 \\ 
5 & 12 & 19 \\ 
9 & 19 & 29 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 5 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 13 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
5 & 1 & 0 \\ 
9 & 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 13 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 5 & 9 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 5 & 9 \\ 
5 & 12 & 19 \\ 
9 & 19 & 29 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Answer (score 0):

We can also do something if the binary form is positive, it will just require complex numbers. In this one, I guess the extra $15$ would be absorbed by dividing each of the two factors by $\sqrt{15}$

$$ f(x,y,z) = 15 x^2 + 20 y^2 + 31 z^2 + 48 yz + 34 zx + 32 xy   $$

$$ f = 15 \left( x + \frac{16y}{15} + \frac{17 z}{15}  \right)^2 + \frac{44}{15} (y + 2 z)^2 \; \; ,   $$
$$ 15 f = (15 x + 16 y + 17 z)^2 + 44 (y+2z)^2   $$
$$  15 f = \left(15 x + (16 + 2i \sqrt {11}) y + (17 + 4i \sqrt {11}) z   \right) \; \cdot \; \left(15 x + (16 - 2i \sqrt {11}) y + (17 - 4i \sqrt {11}) z   \right) $$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 16 }{ 15 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 17 }{ 15 }  & 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
15 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 44 }{ 15 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 16 }{ 15 }  &  \frac{ 17 }{ 15 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
15 & 16 & 17 \\ 
16 & 20 & 24 \\ 
17 & 24 & 31 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
15 & 16 & 17 \\ 
16 & 20 & 24 \\ 
17 & 24 & 31 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 16 }{ 15 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 16 }{ 15 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 16 }{ 15 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
15 & 0 & 17 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 44 }{ 15 }  &  \frac{ 88 }{ 15 }  \\ 
17 &  \frac{ 88 }{ 15 }  & 31 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 17 }{ 15 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 16 }{ 15 }  &  -  \frac{ 17 }{ 15 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 16 }{ 15 }  &  \frac{ 17 }{ 15 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
15 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 44 }{ 15 }  &  \frac{ 88 }{ 15 }  \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 88 }{ 15 }  &  \frac{ 176 }{ 15 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 16 }{ 15 }  & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 16 }{ 15 }  &  \frac{ 17 }{ 15 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
15 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 44 }{ 15 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 16 }{ 15 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 &  - 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
15 & 16 & 17 \\ 
16 & 20 & 24 \\ 
17 & 24 & 31 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 16 }{ 15 }  & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
15 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 44 }{ 15 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 16 }{ 15 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 17 }{ 15 }  & 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
15 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 44 }{ 15 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 16 }{ 15 }  &  \frac{ 17 }{ 15 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
15 & 16 & 17 \\ 
16 & 20 & 24 \\ 
17 & 24 & 31 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

..................